# How can I Modify the parameter values in the specified fields in the toml file using the regular expression

Tags: python, regex, toml

I want to  Modify the parameter values in the specified fields in the toml file using the regular expression In Python language. For example exchanging the value of `name` in [tool.poetry] field not in [tool.pytest.ini_options]

```
[tool.poetry]
version = "0.1.0"
description = "python is good"
name = "template-python"
readme = "README.md"
packages =[
    {include="projectname"}
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.11,<3.13"


[tool.poetry.group.test.dependencies]
pytest = "^8.0.0"


[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "."
addopts = ["-v", "-s", "--import-mode=importlib"]
name = "hello"
```

Python code:

```
def tereg():
    with open('pyproject.toml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        r = f.read()
    reg_name = r'(?<=name = ").*(?=")'
    # reg_name = r'(\[tool\.poetry\][\s\S]*?)name = "(.*)"([\s\S]*?[(\r\n)|\n]\[.*?\])'
    re.sub(reg_name, "nameofproject", r)
```

Run the code, It changes the value in two places [tool.poetry] and [tool.pytest.ini_options], but I just want to change the value of `name` in [tool.poetry]. How to write the regular expression `reg_name` ? Thank you.

Comment: Like this? `(\[tool\.poetry](?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*\nname = ")[^"\n]*(?=")` https://regex101.com/r/xsvNgM/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I think your grouping might be a bit off, wont this be better ? - `"\[tool\.poetry\].*?name\s=\s\"(.*?)\""gs` since the focus is only on the attribute value of name under tools.poetry

Comment: @KaranShishoo The .*? will match too much if there is no name in the current "block" See https://regex101.com/r/oFKUth/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird ahh that is a fair point, would need to be safeguarded against if used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use:

```
(\[tool\.poetry](?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*\nname = ")[^"\n]*(?=")
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[tool\.poetry]`
  - `(?:\n(?!\[[^][]*]).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `[...]`
  - `\nname = "` Match a newline and then `name = "`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^"\n]*` Match optional chars other than `"` or a newline
- `(?=")` Assert " to the right

In the replacement use the capture group 1 value:

```
\1nameofproject
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsvNgM/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qN0nFG).